# Expanding list of databases in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Takes Longer than SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

Is it just me, or does expanding the list of databases in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio take significantly more time than expanding the list of databases in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

If it isn't just me, is there an explanation for this behavior? Whatever it is doing in the background that makes it take longer, can we turn that off? Is it configurable?

I know, it seems trivial, but I am perpetually being surprised at how long this takes.

Comment: Expanding the list where? In the Registered Servers window or the drop down in the connection dialog?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In SQL Management Studio 2008, select the "Databases" node in the Object Explorer.  Then, click View --> Object Explorer Details.  Right click on one of the column headers and uncheck all of the columns besides "Name".  These columns are slowing down the process of expanding the database list.

Comment: Awesome! That makes a huge difference. Thanks.

Comment: This made a huge difference. Had way too many columns showing.

Comment: Never had this slowness issue until my most recent computer (only a year old). SSMS v18 and SQL Server 2019 Express - super slow to expand tables. This answer is over 10 years old and the fix still worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the systems I have worked on have 200 or fewer tables.  That should be near instantaneous.

The only times I've ever seen a slow down is in systems under heavy load or if my network connection to the database server is slow.  In which case it is completely dependent on factors outside my control.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a factor of the DB. You can use the Management Studios from SQL Server 05 and 08 to connect to the same server, and the 2008 one will take longer to bring up the list of databases. Significantly longer.

Comment: Interesting.  Are you running the latest service packs on the machine with management studio installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,expanding the databases was extremely slow on Mng Studio 2012 and 2014 but not on 2008.
The problem was that a lot of databases had the AutoClose property set to True

I used this script to find those databases

```
SELECT name, is_auto_close_on, is_auto_shrink_on FROM master.sys.databases AS dtb 
WHERE is_auto_close_on = 1 OR is_auto_shrink_on = 1
ORDER BY name
```

And then i set the AutoClose property to False on those databases.

From then , the databases node expands instantaneously